# PHP cron script doesn't work as expected for remote update

Tags: php, xml, cron

I have this php code in my updatexml.php file:

```
$url = "http://www.sitetovisit.net/xml/import_xml.php";
copy($url, "shopproducts.xml");
```

Cron is set to open this url each hour and to get xml information from import_xml.php and save it in shopproducts.xml. 2 mins later another cron scrip reads the shopproducts.xml file and updates the database.
I noticed that when I visit http://www.myownsite.net/updatexml.php directly shopproducts.xml file is getting updated and the file gets new date modified and of course updated xml information.
When cron opens that url "http://www.myownsite.net/updatexml.php" the xml date modified is stays the same and the information inside is the oldest when I have visited the url directly.

What am I missing with cron? Doesn't it behaves as human url visit? Why it doesnt update the xml file? Cron path is set correct as at the bottom of updatexml.php file I have mail() funtion that informs me about update.

Please help, Thanks !

Comment: try to debug cron action. Check if is executed for sure, and log

Comment: Daimos, sorry if sounds stupid but how to debug cron action? Isnt it a proof work working script if it sends mail?

Comment: Cron can work fine, but maybe php parser not? You can for example log cron action inside php file. Create log.txt and insert info about runned action with time. If you got email with result of script, use echo to put some information after script is executed. Show us cron command that you use